# Как вызвать не static метод из интерфейса? Java 8

Tags: java, методы, интерфейс

Недавно вышел с основ джавы и сделал тестовый интерфейс, в нем я сделал метод, и пытаюсь получить на него ссылку. static метод интерфейса мне не подходит, ведь иначе его нельзя будет добавить в другие классы.

Код интерфейса:

```
public interface IRadReduce {
    public float getReduce();   
}
```

Получаю ссылку на метод:

```
IRadReduce::getReduce()
```

Пробовал еще вот так

```
IRadReduce.getReduce()
```

У меня есть класс тестовой брони которая имплементирует интерфейс IRadReduce

```
public class AntiRadArmor extends Armor implements IRadReducer{ 
    @Override 
    public float getReduce(int amount) { 
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Также у меня есть класс радиации, где проверяется, что если это IRadReduce, то скорость накапливания радиации должна быть равна значению IRadReduce

```
if (player.inventory.armorInventory[2] != null && player.inventory.armorInventory[2].getItem() instanceof IRadReduce) {
    if(player.ticksExisted % 50 == 0){
        ep.addRadiation(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: функционально так IRadReduce::getReduce, нефункционально так iRadReduce.getReduce()

Comment: Если я пишу IRadReduce::getReduce, то подчёркивает красным, навожу и пишет вот это: The target type of this expression must be a functional . 
@Дмитрий

Comment: так покажите это в коде. как можно угдатать где и что вы пишите?

Comment: Класс самой радиации не имплементирует этот интерфейс, ведь иначе я не смогу для каждого костюма настроить свой показатель защиты

Comment: отформатируйте и добавьте в вопрос, читать же невозможно

Comment: @IR42, добавил в вопрос, извиняюсь за убогое оформление

Comment: всё ещё непонятно, где вы используете (пытаетесь использовать) ссылку на метод?

Comment: вы еще с синтаксисом не освоились , а уже instanceof написали.... но в любом случае в вашем коде попыток вызова метода getReduce() не наблюдается. да и зачем его вызывать, если у вас один класс его имплементирует и тот захордкоженный ноль возвращает

Comment: вот, посмотрите это вопрос. может немного разберетесь с тем, как используется интерфейс. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1120680/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9d/1120992?noredirect=1#comment1937123_1120992

Comment: и еще вот этот. оба вопроса по сути по основам ооп https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1119686/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java-%d0%be%d0%be%d0%bf-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2/1119722#1119722